# How to solve linear programming problem using Python and Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I have a some materials made from chemical elements having a price for each kilo gram:

```
A: { cu: 0.02, mg: 0.3, nc: 0.005, price: 1000 }
```

This means 1 kilo gram of material A is made from 0.02g "cu", 0.3g "mg", 0.005g "nc", and has a price of 1000$. I have some other similar materials:

```
 A: { cu: 0.02, mg: 0.3, nc: 0.005, price: 1000 }  
 B: { cu: 0.033, mg: 0.2, nc: 0.00, price: 1500 }  
 C: { cu: 0.05, mg: 0.35, nc: 0.00, price: 1700 }
```

I want to build a product, lets call it Pr_1, having 10 kilo grams weight, made from materials A, B, and/or C, so the Pr_1 has minimum price. The Pr_1 has some constraints too:

```
Pr_1: {minCu: 0.00, maxCu: 1.2, minMg: 1.2, maxMg: 1.9, minNc: 0, maxNc: 0}
```

This means 10 kilo gram of Pr_1 should have at least 0.00g and at most 1.2g  "cu", also it should have at least 1.2g and at most 1.9g "mg", and it shouldn't have any "nc". As I mentioned, the Pr_1 has to have minimum price among all possible combinations of materials A, B, and C.

So, Let's denote the weights of Pr_1 made from materials A, B, and C as x_A, x_B, and x_C, respectively. The objective is to minimize the total cost:

Minimize:

```
1000*x_A + 1500*x_B + 1700*x_C
```

and we have 3 inequality equations:

```
0.00 <= 0.02*x_A + 0.033*x_B + 0.05*x_C <= 1.2 // cu constraint  
1.2 <= 0.03*x_A + 0.2*x_B + 0.35*x_C <= 1.9 // mg constraint  
0.005*x_A + 0.00*x_B + 0.00*x_C = 0 // nc constraint
```

I can not figure out how can I solve this using Scipy and Python.

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

# Coefficients of the objective function (costs)
c = [1000, 1500, 1700]

# Coefficients of the inequality constraints matrix
A = [
    [-0.02, -0.033, -0.05],   # Cu constraint
    [-0.3, -0.2, -0.35],      # Mg constraint
    [-0.005, 0, 0]            # Nc constraint
]

# Right-hand side of the inequality constraints
b = ???? # I don't know what this should be

# Bounds for each variable (x_A, x_B, x_C)
x_bounds = (0, None)

# Solve the linear programming problem
result = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=[x_bounds, x_bounds, x_bounds], method='highs')

# Print the results
print("Optimal weights for Pr_1 from A, B, and C:", result.x)
print("Minimum cost of Pr_1:", result.fun)
```

Comment: As stated b is the  Right-hand side vector of constraints so `b=[1.2, 1.9,0]`

Comment: @rpanai, what about the lower bound of inequalities?

Comment: I believe that with your constraints as written, the problem is infeasible. You either need to decrease the total mass or increase the tolerances on your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, with your current constraints the problem is infeasible.

With the same constraints you could produce 9 kg. Also, I believe that you should be more careful and explicit with your units, so I demonstrate dimensional management using Pandas. In the end this produces a much more legible output.

Also, at a guess, your `Nc` implies nickel which is actually `Ni`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

materials = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'dollars_per_kg': (1_000, 1_500, 1_700)},
    index=pd.Index(name='material_name', data=('A', 'B', 'C')),
)
materials['dollars_per_g'] = 1e-3*materials['dollars_per_kg']

components = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'min_g': (0.0, 1.2, 0),
        'max_g': (1.2, 1.9, 0),
    },
    index=pd.Index(name='component_name', data=('Cu', 'Mg', 'Ni')),
)

material_components = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'g_per_kg': (
            0.0200, 0.30, 0.005,
            0.0033, 0.20, 0.000,
            0.0500, 0.35, 0.000,
        ),
    },
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        iterables=(materials.index, components.index),
    ),
)
material_components['concentration'] = 1e-3 * material_components['g_per_kg']

mass_kg = 9  # 10 not feasible
mass_g = 1e3*mass_kg

'''
Minimize cost = (A, B, C mass g).(A, B, C dollars per g)
s.t.
A, B, C mass g >= 0
sum(A, B, C mass g) = mass_g
component min <= sum by component(A, B, C mass g) < component max
'''

mass_sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.ones(len(materials)),
    lb=mass_g, ub=mass_g,
)

component_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=material_components['concentration'].unstack('material_name'),
    lb=components['min_g'],
    ub=components['max_g'],
)

result = milp(
    c=materials['dollars_per_g'],
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
    constraints=(
        mass_sum_constraint,
        component_constraint,
    ),
)
if not result.success:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
print(result.message, end='\n\n')

materials['mass_g'] = result.x
materials['dollars'] = result.x * materials['dollars_per_g']
material_components['mass_g'] = material_components['concentration'] * materials['mass_g']
components['mass_g'] = material_components['mass_g'].groupby('component_name').sum()

print('Materials:')
print(materials, end='\n\n')
print('Components:')
print(components, end='\n\n')
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)

Materials:
               dollars_per_kg  dollars_per_g  mass_g  dollars
material_name                                                
A                        1000            1.0    -0.0     -0.0
B                        1500            1.5  9000.0  13500.0
C                        1700            1.7     0.0      0.0

Components:
                min_g  max_g  mass_g
component_name                      
Cu                0.0    1.2  0.0297
Mg                1.2    1.9  1.8000
Ni                0.0    0.0  0.0000
```

To find the maximum total mass, change your objective:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

materials = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'dollars_per_kg': (1_000, 1_500, 1_700)},
    index=pd.Index(name='material_name', data=('A', 'B', 'C')),
)
materials['dollars_per_g'] = 1e-3*materials['dollars_per_kg']

components = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'min_g': (0.0, 1.2, 0),
        'max_g': (1.2, 1.9, 0),
    },
    index=pd.Index(name='component_name', data=('Cu', 'Mg', 'Ni')),
)

material_components = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'g_per_kg': (
            0.0200, 0.30, 0.005,
            0.0033, 0.20, 0.000,
            0.0500, 0.35, 0.000,
        ),
    },
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        iterables=(materials.index, components.index),
    ),
)
material_components['concentration'] = 1e-3 * material_components['g_per_kg']

mass_kg = 9  # 10 not feasible
mass_g = 1e3*mass_kg

'''
Minimize cost = (A, B, C mass g).(A, B, C dollars per g)
Or: maximize total mass
s.t.
A, B, C mass g >= 0
sum(A, B, C mass g) = mass_g
component min <= sum by component(A, B, C mass g) < component max
'''

mass_sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.ones(len(materials)),
    lb=mass_g, ub=mass_g,
)

component_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=material_components['concentration'].unstack('material_name'),
    lb=components['min_g'],
    ub=components['max_g'],
)

result = milp(
    # c=materials['dollars_per_g'],  # to minimize price
    c=-np.ones_like(materials['dollars_per_g']),  # to maximize total mass
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
    constraints=(
        # mass_sum_constraint,  # to ask for a fixed total mass
        component_constraint,
    ),
)
if not result.success:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
print(result.message, end='\n\n')

materials['mass_g'] = result.x
materials['dollars'] = result.x * materials['dollars_per_g']
material_components['mass_g'] = material_components['concentration'] * materials['mass_g']
components['mass_g'] = material_components['mass_g'].groupby('component_name').sum()

print('Materials:')
print(materials, end='\n\n')
print('Components:')
print(components, end='\n\n')
print('Material components:')
print(material_components)
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)

Materials:
               dollars_per_kg  dollars_per_g  mass_g  dollars
material_name                                                
A                        1000            1.0     0.0      0.0
B                        1500            1.5  9500.0  14250.0
C                        1700            1.7     0.0      0.0

Components:
                min_g  max_g   mass_g
component_name                       
Cu                0.0    1.2  0.03135
Mg                1.2    1.9  1.90000
Ni                0.0    0.0  0.00000

Material components:
                              g_per_kg  concentration   mass_g
material_name component_name                                  
A             Cu                0.0200       0.000020  0.00000
              Mg                0.3000       0.000300  0.00000
              Ni                0.0050       0.000005  0.00000
B             Cu                0.0033       0.000003  0.03135
              Mg                0.2000       0.000200  1.90000
              Ni                0.0000       0.000000  0.00000
C             Cu                0.0500       0.000050  0.00000
              Mg                0.3500       0.000350  0.00000
              Ni                0.0000       0.000000  0.00000
```

Comment: How can I find the nearest feasible value? (like 9 in your case)

Comment: Change the cost so that it maximizes total weight instead of minimizing total price

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get that, could you please tell me another way?

Comment: That's the only way. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for your edition and explanation.

Comment: For the first scenario, where we want to have a fixed weight with a minimum price, where the problem is infeasible for some weights, can we set a range for weight? For example, we say for the weight from 8 to 10?

Comment: Easily - replace `lb=mass_g, ub=mass_g,` with `lb=mass_lower_g, ub=mass_upper_g`

Answer (score 1):

System as defined in your post can be written as follow:

```
from scipy import optimize

c = [1000, 1500, 1700]
```

We need to duplicate both constraints and put it in the form `A_ub @ x <= b_ub` only (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)):

```
A_ub = [
    [0.02,  0.033,  0.05],    # Normal inequality, stands for 0.02*x_A + 0.033*x_B + 0.05*x_C <= 1.2
    [0.3,   0.2,    0.35],
    [-0.02,  -0.033, -0.05],  # Reversed inequality, stands for 0.00 <= 0.02*x_A + 0.033*x_B + 0.05*x_C
    [-0.3,   -0.2,   -0.35],
]

b_ub = [1.2, 1.9, 0.0, -1.2]
```

You also need a strict equality:

```
A_eq = [
    [0.005, 0., 0.]
]
b_eq = [0.]
```

We bind everything together:

```
result = optimize.linprog(
    c,
    A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub,
    A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq,
    bounds=[(0., None)] * 3,
    method='highs'
)
# x: array([-0.        ,  0.        ,  3.42857143])
```

Notice `0.005*x_A + 0.00*x_B + 0.00*x_C = 0` constraint forces `x_A = 0`.

An alternative to `optimize.linprog` is [`optimize.milp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html):

```
c = [1000, 1500, 1700]

A = [
    [0.02,  0.033,  0.05],
    [0.3,   0.2,    0.35],
    [0.005, 0.,     0.],
]

b_lb = [0.0, 1.2, 0.0]
b_ub = [1.2, 1.9, 0.0]

optimize.milp(c=c, constraints=[optimize.LinearConstraint(A, b_lb, b_ub)])
# x: array([-0.        ,  0.        ,  3.42857143])
```

Which also allows integral solution constraints:

```
optimize.milp(c=c, constraints=[optimize.LinearConstraint(A, b_lb, b_ub)], integrality=[1, 1, 1])
# x: array([0., 1., 3.])
```

Comment: Would you please explain your solution?

Comment: You don't _need_ to duplicate any constraints if you use `milp` instead of `linprog`.

Comment: @Reinderien, updated with `milp` alternative

Comment: Using `milp`, the result is: `fun: 5828.571428571429` and `x: [-0.000e+00  0.000e+00  3.429e+00]`, which means I need to pick just material C, right?
And if the x was for example `x: [-0.000e+00, 2.520e+00, 3.429e+00]`, it means I have to pick material B and C with ratio 2.52 and 3.429, is it correct?

Comment: How is (0, 0, 3.42) a valid solution? OP asked for 10 kg total and modelled the decision variables as individual masses.